# Disable old-style constructors (PHP4-)

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

I am working on an MVC framework in PHP.

I have several controller classes called "index" with methods called "index" within them. The classes do not have __construct() methods.
Inevitably, this is resulting in PHP calling the "index" method as the constructor instead, using the old PHP4 convention of the constructor being the method with the same name as the class.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour or do I have to define an empty __construct() to prevent it? (Or just change my own coding style so I don't have methods with the same name as their classes.)

I want PHP5 to stop parsing for the PHP4 constructors essentially.

Ilmiont

Comment: There's no option for that. Rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have been down the same road with MVC frameworks before and I have never heard of an index() function being called like this. Upon instanciation it will call the __constructor if present or do nothing. When calling your controller you should be geting the class and method name and checking if they exist and if they do then instantiate it. However if you have the same general setup as me you should have a registry storing all of your variables being passed to the controller when you create an instance, then when/if the view is called from index it should pass the altered registry to the view